# How to display the mean value in a R plot using ggstatsplot

Tags: r, violin-plot

I have the following R code:

```
set.seed(1) 
df <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:10,100,rep=TRUE)),
group=sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "F"), size=100, replace=TRUE))

##Code
ggbetweenstats(
  data = df,
  x = group,
  y = X1,
  xlab = "Group",
  ylab = "Support",
  plot.type = "violin",
  type = "np",
  conf.level = 0.95,
  violin.args = list(width = 0.9, alpha = 0.2),
  title = "",
  messages = FALSE,
  mean.plotting = TRUE,
  package = "ggsci",
  palette = "default_nejm"
)
```

which produces a nonparametric violin plot and displays the median number. I want to add the mean value to the plot as well. I included `mean.plotting = TRUE` but it didn't work.

Comment: Why do you use `type = np`?

Comment: @quinten because the data distribution is non-normal so I needed to use a nonparametric method.

Comment: `mean.plotting = TRUE` does not work, because the default is already set to TRUE.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the simplest way to do this is create both parametric and non-parametric versions:

```r
pmed <- ggbetweenstats(
  data = df,
  x = group,
  y = X1,
  xlab = "Group",
  ylab = "Support",
  plot.type = "violin",
  type = "nonparametric",
  conf.level = 0.95,
  violin.args = list(width = 0.9, alpha = 0.2),
  title = "",
  messages = FALSE,
  package = "ggsci",
  palette = "default_nejm"
)

pmean <- ggbetweenstats(
  data = df,
  x = group,
  y = X1,
  xlab = "Group",
  ylab = "Support",
  plot.type = "violin",
  type = "parametric",
  centrality.label.args = list(nudge_x = -0.4),
  conf.level = 0.95,
  violin.args = list(width = 0.9, alpha = 0.2),
  title = "",
  messages = FALSE,
  package = "ggsci",
  palette = "default_nejm"
)
```

then copy the appropriate layers of the parametric plot over to the non-parametric one.

```r
pmed$layers[[6]] <- pmean$layers[[4]]
pmed$layers[[7]] <- pmean$layers[[5]]
```

Which results in:

```r
pmed
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how the bars could be reordered? For instance, if I want to have bars in the following order: D  F C A  B

Comment: @Santiago99 you need to make the groups factors with the desired order. For example, instead of passing `df` to `ggbetweenstats`, try passing `within(df, group <- factor(group, c("D", "F", "C", "A", "B")))`